# Bug in tag search results

Tags: bug, tag-search

I've searched for "tidesdk" in the Tags page of StackOverflow, clicked the tag I wanted and that left me with this:

[image: Featured tab]

The URL says to be showing questions tagged with "tidesdk", but the page says I'm in the Featured tab.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing anything, except that the last time you looked at a page for tags you were on the Featured tab. The site remembers your tab choice.

There aren't any questions with bounties, so no questions are listed. That's what the system is telling you; rather than leaving it completely blank and you wondering where all the questions went.

Click one of the other tabs ("newest", "votes", etc.) and you'll see the questions you were expecting.

So, this is very much [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Answer (score 0):

This featured tab is for the questions that have Bounty, thus the name Featured.

At the very particular time, there are no questions with this tag and who have a bounty offered. So that's why there are no questions for you to see at the spot.

> Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

Is a note for you, if you want to select a different tab, then you can select any of the tabs from the Navigation menu above.