# "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" - shouldn't that be 'tag' instead of 'tab'?

Tags: bug, tags, spelling

I just removed a tag on [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) from all questions and then reloaded the tagged questions page. It was empty, as expected, but the suggestion is to *select a different ta**b***. It think it should read *ta**g*** there.

> Questions tagged [language-varieties]
>
> The language-varieties tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?
>
> Learn more… Top users Synonyms
>
> 0 questions
>
> **No questions found. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?**

Comment: [Bug in tag search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223223) | [Why did clicking on a tag take me to a nonexistent tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88036)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Text incorrectly says "tab" instead of "tag" when a user looks at a tag with no questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397189/4642212) on MSO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's intentional. Check [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags?tab=Bounties) which sports the same message as you saw:

[image]

What happens here is that I list all questions with the [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) tag ... with a bounty on them. Currently, there are none, but if you select a different tab, e.g. 'Newest' or 'Active', you do see questions.

Of course, if there are no questions at all in the tag anymore, select a different tab won't help. But such tags are automatically pruned every 24 hours, so the situation you describe won't happen that often.